# Zend 2 smtp Mail not working on godaddy

Tags: php, zend-framework2, smtp

I have successfully configured the smtp connection on local but when i am using it on live go-daddy its throwing e error that connection has been refused.

```
$smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();  
$smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
            ->setConnectionClass('login')
            ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
            ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                'username' => 'XXXXXX@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'XXXXX!',
                'ssl' => 'tls',

            ))
            ->setPort('465');

$transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
```

i have tried **port 587 also**. Would be great if someone could guide me how to solve this . Stuck over this from few days . thanks

Comment: Does Godaddy have ssl/tls packages required by default, maybe not?

Answer (score 0):

See configuration of your godaddy mail server. I use following host for godaddy account -
mail domain: smtpout.secureserver.net
host: 173.201.193.101
port: 25

Above configuration works fine for me. Please use your own username and password that is not mention here. Also I use SMTP for mail transport.